# The textField with net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.read.only" value="false" in detail band not rendered in Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a report built with help of *JasperReports 6.16.0* and contains some fields like:

```
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="350" y="0" width="60" height="15" uuid="474e8822-4d2c-43d2-b18b-a0a68ac8a055">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.read.only" value="false"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.type" value="Text"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="5" rightPadding="5">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{anzahl}!= null && $F{anzahl} > 0 ? $F{anzahl}: "-")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

The problem is, that the pdf gets rendered fine in every pdf-reader I tried, but not in Acrobat Reader (DC).

The output result at Kofax application:

[image: Kofax]

And this is how the same pdf file looks like at Acrobat Reader:
[image: Acrobat]

What happens is, that ONLY the first textfield gets rendered and the following textfields are blank.

A first guess was the uuid of the reportElement, so I removed it. But the result was the same.

The generated pdf without *net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.** properties looks fine at Acrobat Reader.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Everything works fine without the .pdf.* properties and the version I'm using is 6.16.0

Comment: Some links to how it looks in different pdf readers
https://postimg.cc/QFXgr5Jf  Kofax <--- correct
https://postimg.cc/RNmKcfyv    Acrobat <--- wrong